# how to use internal files stored at /data/data/[package]/files in android?

Tags: android, drawable, imageswitcher

I downloaded several files from url and stored it as i mention path above. 
i want to use those files as ImageSwitcher's source in a loop, one after another image will change after some time interval.

so please help me out.
is it possible that i will make an array of stored files as we make an array of drawble?

Answer (score 0):

[Internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

If these are static files, put them in res/raw, open them with openRawResource, and have your build system make a static array of R.raw.whatevers available to you.

Comment: These are not static files, i m done with static files already. These file are changing  from server side, and because of that , ImageSwitcher have to change image according to it.

Comment: Which only means that you won't have the nice compile-time array, and that you'll deal with string names instead of resource IDs. Follow the link.

Comment: @Upadhyay oh, and use `getContext().fileList()`